# Forbidden error when making stripe payment

Tags: reactjs, express, stripe-payments

So I make stripe checkount in my frontend:

```
const StripeCheckoutButton = ({ price }) => {
  const priceForStripe = price * 100;
  const publishableKey = "pk_test_QxG1LDucNFRDvVPJcgoQDsph00A2YvKyS4";

  const onToken = (token) => {
    axios({
      url: "payment",
      method: "post",
      data: {
        amount: priceForStripe,
        token: token,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        alert("succesful payment");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Payment Error: ", error);
        alert(
          "There was an issue with your payment! Please make sure you use the provided credit card."
        );
      });
  };
```

I make variable to my publishablekey, and make component:

```
<StripeCheckout
  label="Pay now"
  name=
  billingAddress
  shippingAddress
  description={`Your total is $${price}`}
  amount={priceForStripe}
  panelLabel="Pay now"
  token={onToken}
  stripeKey={publishableKey}
/>
```

Obviously I make name string I just deleted to paste here...

After that I make server.js in my backend, to handle payment:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const enforce = require("express-sslify");

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") require("dotenv").config();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));
app.use(cors());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

  app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, (error) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Server running on port " + port);
});

app.get("/service-worker.js", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build", "service-worker.js"));
});

app.post("/payment", (req, res) => {
  const body = {
    source: req.body.token.id,
    amount: req.body.amount,
    currency: "usd",
  };

  stripe.charges.create(body, (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
    if (stripeErr) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: stripeErr });
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({ success: stripeRes });
    }
  });
});
```

I make .env variable in my root, to store my secretkey, STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=mykey like this, and when I want to make payment I get back 403 error, and I checked everything, my keys, my packages, my .env file and I don't know the problem.

[image]

Maybe i use older version, that's the problem.
Anyone know what"s the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the 403 Forbidden error because you're using `express-sslify`.  Here's the first paragraph of [its readme](https://github.com/florianheinemann/express-sslify/blob/master/README.md) (emphasis added)

> This simple module enforces HTTPS connections on any incoming GET and HEAD requests. In case of a non-encrypted HTTP request, express-sslify automatically redirects to an HTTPS address using a 301 permanent redirect. **Any other type of request (e.g., POST) will fail with a 403 error message.**

You should disable `express-sslify` when testing locally without HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah it worked. And what about production?
if i will build.

Comment: You should enable it in production, or whenever everything is running over HTTPS.  When everything is using HTTPS it should work just fine.